# CSS -webkit-box-shadow not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css

I am using `-webkit-box-shadow` to have a background color on my input text boxes and its working in Safari and Chrome, but not working (as I am told in Microsoft Edge) How come? Here is my CSS:

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=password],
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #141416 inset !important;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuqpncrt/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out the `box-shadow` property without the webkit prefix?

You can use both at the same time:

```
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #141416 inset !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #141416 inset !important;
        border: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        color: #fff;
        outline: 0;
        border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: No, I have not, I don't have Microsoft Edge on Windows so I can't see the issue.

Comment: I tried your code on Edge v84 and it worked. Support for the webkit prefix might vary by version, so I would add the prefix-free box-shadow property along with the webkit-prefixed one you already got.

Comment: Yea, I just applied the code to the live site, waiting to hear back if it worked. Is there a Microsoft Edge Simulator? the Mac version of Microsoft Edge does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Make sure they're not using IE